# Двієчник, двоєчник чи двійошник?

Tags: орфографія

СУМ наводить [двоєчник](http://sum.in.ua/s/dvojechnyk)

slovnyk.ua каже [двієчник](http://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%C4%C2%B2%AA%D7%CD%C8%CA)

В реальному житті я чую двійошник

То як правильно?

Answer (score 9):

З «[Як ми говоримо](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%BA_%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE)» Антоненка-Давидовича:

> **Двоєчник, двієчник, двійкар**
>
> Слово *двієчник* утворилось від іменника *двійка*, але правило чергування *і* з *о* та е в відкритому складі, на зразок *стіл* —
>   *столу*, *піч* — *печі* тут ні до чого. У цьому випадку діє закон не фонетичний, а морфологічний, що розглядає походження слова, отже, не
>   звукові зміни в ньому.
>
> Візьмімо іменник *кіл*: у родовому та інших відмінках, де буде відкритий склад, за фонетичним законом чергування *і* перейде в *о* —
>   *кола, колу, колом, на колі.* А якщо ми візьмемо похідне від іменника *кіл* слово *кілочок*, то, хоч тут перший склад — відкритий (*кі*), і в ньому залишилось, а не перейшло в *о* (*кілочка*). Чому? Бо тут уже
>   діє закон морфологічний, який не вважає на відкритий склад, а вимагає
>   вимовляти слово з тим звуком, від якого це слово утворилось.
>
> Те саме можна сказати й про слово *двієчник*, у якому *і* не переходить в *о*, а залишається, бо воно було в слові *двійка*, від
>   якого походить.
>
> Синонімом до слова *двієчник* може бути таке ж похідне від іменника *двійка* слово *двійкар*, утворене за аналогією до інших
>   іменників із суфіксом *-к*-, наприклад: *шапкар* — від слова *шапка*,
>   *байкар* — від *байка*.
>
> Отже, якщо підходити до цього питання науково, то буде — *двієчник* або *двійкар*, але не *двоєчник*.

Повний текст статті [тут](http://slovopedia.org.ua/34/53396/33135.html).